# how to use ng click and pass the id in google map pop window using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i have two stores in database and am trying to get stores in google map marker is pointing that two stores.i have ng-click in that info window to pass id here ng-click is not working is there any idea to pass id through ng-click

```js
.controller('MapCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window',
 
function ($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
    $http.get('****').success(function (data, dealers, response) {
        function initialize() {
            var serverData = data;
            $scope.locations = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
                var modal = [
                data[i].Store_Name, data[i].S_Location.Latitude, data[i].S_Location.Longitude, i, 'images/arrow.svg', data[i].S_Address];
                $scope.locations.push(modal); 
            }
            console.log($scope.locations);
            //---------------------------------------------------------
            //console i am getting like this
            var locations = [
                ['nokia store', '12.971599', '77.594563', '1', 'images/arrow.svg.svg', '55a78953815356700bee698f'],
                ['samsung store', '12.9065534', '77.5774802', '2', 'images/arrow.svg.svg', '55a786d1815356700bee6982'], ];
            //----------------------------------------------------------
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 13,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9667, 77.5667),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var marker, i;
            for (i = 0; i < $scope.locations.length; i++) {
                //console.log($scope.locations[i][1]);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.locations[i][1], $scope.locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    icon: $scope.locations[i][4],
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent('<div class="marker-box"><div class="marker-title">' + $scope.locations[i][0] + '</div><input type="button" value="Book Now" name="Book Now" ng-click="getid(' + $scope.locations[i][5] + ') "/></div>');
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
            $scope.map = map;
        }
        $scope.getid(id) {
            console.log(id);
        }
    });
```

since 3 days i'm trying i can't able to solve.help me out

Answer (score 0):

So in your code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent('<div class="marker-box"><div class="marker-title">' + $scope.locations[i][0] + '</div><input type="button" value="Book Now" name="Book Now" ng-click="getid(' + $scope.locations[i][5] + ') "/></div>');
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
```

your call back function does not run until marker is clicked. By the time it's clicked, the scope probably does not know what "i" is. My guess is "i" becomes `$scope.locations.length+1`.

One things you can try:

put the above code in a secondary function, then call it from the main thread instead of running it directly from main thred. IE:

```
main code:{
//your code
for (i = 0; i < $scope.locations.length; i++){
   function_name(parameter 1, i);
}

function function_name= above code;
```

Note the above is sudo code, please implement it and try it. Hope this solves it.

Comment: i is getting the value.but when click on the button it doesn't passing the value

Comment: did you try printing i before infowindow.setContent('<div class="marker-box"><div class="marker-title">' + $scope.locations[i][0] + '</div><input type="button" value="Book Now" name="Book Now" ng-click="getid(' + $scope.locations[i][5] + ') "/></div>'); ? Check if it has correct value